# Passing a MAP from LWC to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass a map from LWC to my apex.
.js

```javascript
handleFieldSelected(event){
        this.apiName= event.detail.realApiName;
        this.fieldValue = event.detail.fieldValue;
        this.fieldToUpdate.push({Key : this.apiName , value : this.fieldValue});
}

handleSave(){
    alert(this.fieldToUpdate);
    saveFields({ fieldsToUpdate : this.fieldToUpdate})
        .then(result => {
            this.message = result;
            //this.navigateToRecord(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(error);
            console.log (error);
        });
    }
```

My apex class which's not completed yet.

```apex
@AuraEnabled
public static void fieldSave(Map<String, String> fieldsToUpdate){
    system.debug(fieldsToUpdate);
    for (String key : fieldsToUpdate.keySet()){
        String rightValue = fieldsToUpdate.get(Key);
    }
    //system.debug(sncFieldsToUpdate);
}
```

I can see the data in the alert message which is inside `handleSave()`.
But the `System.debug` inside the apex method throws null reference error. The map is null.

Comment: I want to pass api name as key and value as the value of that field. i have removed [] from fieldToUpdate .Now I am using below code this.fieldToUpdate = {"Key" : this.apiName , "value" : this.rightValue};  My main purpose is to pass the api name and field value list to apex. How can I achieve that ? Can it be done other than Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your JavaScript is making an Array of key-value pairs. In Apex, that would be:

```
public class KeyValuePair {
  @AuraEnabled public String key { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String value { get; set; }
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void fieldSave(List<KeyValuePair> fieldsToUpdate)
```

Or:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void fieldSave(List<Map<String, String>> fieldsToUpdate)
```

...

Maps are just fine, if you want to do it that way, but you need an Object on the JavaScript side:

```
fieldsToUpdate = {};
handleFieldSelected(event){
  this.fieldsToUpdate[event.detail.realApiName] = event.detail.fieldValue;
}
```

Which would then match your current Apex Code.

Comment: can you give an example on  "Maps are just fine, if you want to do it that way, but you need an Object on the JavaScript side:"

Comment: what if we want to have map of map of key value pair, for example key being object name and value being fieldsupdate map.